# run/import a script in Ipython

Tags: python, ipython, anaconda, spyder

I want to run a script (OutputVariables.py) within my main file in IPython. 
My main file includes these lines:

```
import numpy as np # first line
import math        # second line    
run OutputVaribles # third line
```

When hitting F5, I get a syntax error with the run command (invalid syntax). If I select each line separately and hit  F9, it runs the script. Similarly, implementing run OutputVaribles in the console also works. Could someone tell me what is wrong here?

Note: My main file and OutputVariables.py file are in the same direction. I have installed Anaconda. I am using Spyder as my editor and compiling in IPython console.

Comment: you're trying to execute a file from within IPython?

Comment: You probably mean to `import OutputVariables`

Comment: Importing also works, but if I only run my main file within the console. If I hit F5, it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try writing the code you want to run in `OutputVaribles.py` within a function, then, within `main.py` import that function and call it?

**OutputVaribles.py**

```
def your_function():
    # your code block here
```

**main.py**

```
from OutputVaribles import your_function

import numpy as np
import math

your_function() # runs your code block
```

Then you can execute your `main.py` with

```
python main.py
```

within your console.

Comment: It works fine this way. Thank you! I should admit that I would not define a function for this in Matlab, but just import the script. I should get used to Python language :))